# Jquery não executa por causa de sintaxe

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

Analisei minha sintaxe e a princípio está certa:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val()==$(this).attr('placeholder'))
        $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='')
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });


    $( ".soluctionsBenefits" ).click(function() {     
        $( ".soluctionsBenefitsShow" ).show();
        $( ".soluctionsDescriptionShow" ).hide();
        $( ".soluctionsApplicationsShow" ).hide();
    });
}
```

Porém, aponta erro no console:

[image: Erro na consola do navegador]

Que indica a seguinte linha no meu código:

[image: Indicação do erro no meu código]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se observares o erro:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Que traduzido fica:

> Erro de sintaxe: Falta `)` após a lista de argumentos

Conseguimentos entender, com a ajuda da indicação da linha onde ocorreu o erro, que falta fechar os parênteses do método [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), cujo mesmo recebe como argumento uma função a executar após o DOM estar disponível.

## Código retificado

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val()==$(this).attr('placeholder'))
        $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='')
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });

    $( ".soluctionsBenefits" ).click(function() {     
        $( ".soluctionsBenefitsShow" ).show();
        $( ".soluctionsDescriptionShow" ).hide();
        $( ".soluctionsApplicationsShow" ).hide();
    });
}); // Faltava fechar os parênteses aqui
```

## Otimização

Aproveitando a resposta, fica uma dica para minimizar a interação com o DOM dado que fazes várias chamadas aos elementos nos métodos [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) e [`.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').focus(function(){

    // colocar elemento em cache para evitar andar sempre a procurar o mesmo
    var $this = $( this );  

    if ( $this.val()==$this.attr('placeholder') )
      $this.val('');

    }).blur(function(){

      var $this = $( this ); 

      if ( $this.val()=='' )
        $this.val( $this.attr('placeholder') );
    });

    $( ".soluctionsBenefits" ).click(function() {

      $( ".soluctionsBenefitsShow" ).show();

      // esconder vários elementos ao mesmo tempo
      $( ".soluctionsDescriptionShow, .soluctionsApplicationsShow" ).hide(); 
    });
});
```

Essencialmente, melhoramos duas coisas:

1. Evitar andar sempre a procurar o elemento em `.focus()` ou `.blur()` colocando-o em cache:

   ```
   var $this = $(this);
   ```
2. Esconder vários elementos de uma só vez evitando múltiplas linhas de código para o mesmo efeito:

   ```
   $( ".soluctionsDescriptionShow, .soluctionsApplicationsShow" ).hide();
   ```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Horas na frente do computador geram esses descuidos, eheh.

Answer (score 2):

É porque realmente falta um `)`, que é no final para fechar a clausula do `document.ready`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val()==$(this).attr('placeholder'))
        $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='')
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });

    $( ".soluctionsBenefits" ).click(function() {     
        $( ".soluctionsBenefitsShow" ).show();
        $( ".soluctionsDescriptionShow" ).hide();
        $( ".soluctionsApplicationsShow" ).hide();
    });
}) // <---- AQUI
```